# Given $\mathbf{X_1}\gt\mathbf{X_2}$, prove $(\mathbf{I} - e^{\mathbf{A}t})\mathbf{X_1} \gt(\mathbf{I} - e^{\mathbf{A}t})\mathbf{X_2}$

Tags: matrices, inequality

Vector $\mathbf{X_1}$ and $\mathbf{X_2}$ are of dimension $(N\times 1)$.
If vector $\mathbf{X_1}$'s each element is larger than $\mathbf{X_2}$ i.e. $\mathbf{X_1}>\mathbf{X_2}$.

How can we prove 
$(\mathbf{I} - e^{\mathbf{A}t})\mathbf{X_1} \gt(\mathbf{I} - e^{\mathbf{A}t})\mathbf{X_2}$ ?

$\mathbf{A}$ is a $(N\times N)$symmetric, negative definite matrix and is diagonal dominant. $e^{\mathbf{A}t}$ is the matrix exponential of $\mathbf{A}$.

Thank you.

Right now, I have $(\mathbf{I} - e^{\mathbf{A}t})^{-1}$'s all the elements are positive and it is symmetric. So, what's next?

Comment: For $t>0$ or $t\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: only consider $t > 0$. Thank you

Comment: An invertible matrix $M$ is monotone if and only if $M^{-1} \ge 0$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/368260/251257

Answer (score 0):

$(\mathbf{I}-e^{\mathbf{A}t})$ is a monotone, since $(\mathbf{I}-e^{\mathbf{A}t})^{-1}\geq 0$,which means with all the positive entries.

$(\mathbf{I}-e^{\mathbf{A}t})\cdot (\mathbf{X}_1-\mathbf{X}_2)\geq \mathbf{0}$. Then, $(\mathbf{I}-e^{\mathbf{A}t})^{-1}(\mathbf{I}-e^{\mathbf{A}t})\cdot (\mathbf{X}_1-\mathbf{X}_2)\geq \mathbf{0}$.

Then, $\mathbf{X}_1-\mathbf{X}_2\geq \mathbf{0}$.